# read from xml into a variable (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

I am trying to load an attribute from a simple xml file.
The xml contents look like:

```
<top>
    <levels>
        <number>4</number>
    </levels>
</top>
```

And I want to get that "4" into a variable and I can't figure it out how to do it correctly.

I tried something like that:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("levelsXml.xml");
var levels = from query in xdoc.Descendants("levels")
select nrOfLevelsCompleted = Convert.ToInt32(query.Element("number"));
```

Answer (score 2):

If your xml file always has a single `<levels />` element, you can try

```
int levels = Convert.ToInt32(xdoc.Descendants("levels")
                                 .Single().Element("number").Value);
```

Comment: Yes my xml always has a single    <levels> element, and i won't mind having less tags,actually i only need a number. I tried the code but it crashes..

Comment: @Varkaf [This snippet](http://pastie.org/3457597) works for me in linqpad. Could the crash be unrelated to this snippet ?

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that i used Build Action:Resource.
Oh and now how could i change that number?

Comment: @Varkaf If that's the only variable in the file then the easiest method would be to get the xml string (`var xml = String.Format("<top><levels><number>{0}</number></levels></top>", 10);`) and use file io methods to write to that file.